# Facebook api doesn't return information if the range of time is set before 1 january 2017

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook api doesn't return information if the range of time is set before 1 january 2017? For example, i make this request {profile_id}/posts?since=1480543200&until=1483135200 and I recieved nothing, even an error.

This request supposed to give me all the posts of the profile between December 1 and 31 December 2016. I do something wrong? If I make a similar request, but i set as time range a date from 2017 and everythings it's going well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a facebook bug.
and it's fixed.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2297783020445879/

Answer (score 0):

me/posts?since=1480543200&until=1483135200 
or
me/posts?since=2017-01-01&until=2017-12-31